# Rendertron not responding on development or staging server

Tags: web-crawler, seo, rendering, bots, rendertron

I have configured rendition on my development machine as well as staging machine when I check it throws following error.

```
Error: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID at https://rovb-staging2.com/men at navigate (/home/ubuntu/rendertron/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:622:37) at <anonymous> at process._tickCallback
response does not exist
```

if I am rendering our live production site it will work perfectly even I try to render facebook and google pages it showing perfect
I am confusing that it is SSL error or what?